# Browser render undesired P before and after an UL

Tags: html

Check this html code

```
<p>test</p>
<p>
  <ul>
    <li>
    <span style=\"line-height: 1.42857;\">1
    </span>
    <br>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span style=\"line-height: 1.42857;\">2&nbsp;
    </span>
    <br>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span style=\"line-height: 1.42857;\">3
    </span>
    <br>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span style=\"line-height: 1.42857;\">4
    </span>
    <br>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>
    <span style=\"line-height: 20px;\">more text
    </span>
  </p>
</p>
```

For some reason, before and after the `<ul>` an empty `<p>` it's being rendered (i've tried chrome and ff so far).

Check this [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/pkxjNNlYS6BJ7L949IkQ?p=preview) and try inspect the result, you will see something like this

```
<body>
    <p>test
</p>
<p> <----------THIS 
  </p>
<ul>
    <li>
    <span style="\&quot;line-height:" 1.42857;\"="">1
    </span>
    <br>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span style="\&quot;line-height:" 1.42857;\"="">2&nbsp;
    </span>
    <br>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span style="\&quot;line-height:" 1.42857;\"="">3
    </span>
    <br>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span style="\&quot;line-height:" 1.42857;\"="">4
    </span>
    <br>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>
    <span style="\&quot;line-height:" 20px;\"="">more text
    </span>
  </p>
<p></p> <-------------- AND THIS 


</body>
```

Can't figure out why. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to nest tags incorrectly. A `<p>` tag can't contain other `<p>` or list (`<ul>` or `<ol>`) tags.

From [**the specification**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element):

> List elements (in particular, [ol](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element) and [ul](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) elements) cannot be children of [p](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) elements. When a sentence contains a bulleted list, therefore, one might wonder how it should be marked up.
>
> ...
>
> Authors wishing to conveniently style such "logical" paragraphs consisting of multiple "structural" paragraphs can use the [div](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) element instead of the [p](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) element.

What you are seeing is the browser's attempt to handle invalid markup ([misnested tags](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#misnested-tags:-b-i-/b-/i)) by providing closing and opening tags for mismatched opening and closing tags, respectively. When the browser sees the `<ul>`, it closes the still-open `<p>`. And when it sees the final `</p>` in your example, it provides a `<p>` to match.

As Quentin's answer pointed out, you should make use of an [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

Side note: you have a lot of `\"`s in your HTML where you should have just `"`. I assume that's because this HTML is actually being prepared by PHP or some other language, but that's why you're getting weird-looking attributes like `style="\&quot;line-height:" 1.42857;\"=""`.

Comment: Yep, the escaped quotes are there because i grabbed the code from a database column and forgot to unescape them all.

Answer (score 6):

Paragraphs cannot contain lists (or other paragraphs).

The end tag for a paragraph is optional.

The UL start tag closes the P element implicitly.

[Validators](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) are useful tools.